# Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.BizTalk2004.Host.Delete error, but not using Biztalk?

Tags: msbuild, compiler-errors, biztalk, microsoft.sdc.tasks

I have a WCF service and I've recently upgraded from .NET 3.5/TFS2008 to .NET 4.0/TFS2010. I'm been debugging an team build error for the last couple of days and I can't quite figure why I'm receiving the error. I've encountered the error twice.

1. When compiling a Web Deployment project

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets
>   (1728): The "Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.BizTalk2004.Host.Delete" task could
>   not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks\Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.BizTalk.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM,
>   Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

1. When compiling a WiX project

> C:\Builds\24\DCFServices2010\Release
>   4.0\Sources\Bin\wix3-binaries\Wix.targets (1600): The "Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.BizTalk2004.Host.Delete" task could not be loaded
>   from the assembly C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks\Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.BizTalk.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM,
>   Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

In case 1 I've 'fixed' it by reverting back to WebDeployment v9.0 - Not really a fix however.
In case of error 2, I haven't found a solution and I could really use some help!

Facts:

1. I use Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks and I've tried different versions - same result.
2. I do not use any Biztalk releated libraries or have any BizTalk related code
3. This is a VS2010, .NET 4.0 project and the project compiles on a TFS2010 Build agent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is a namespace conflict, in that you have more than on "Delete" task available.  [this link](http://sdctasks.codeplex.com/discussions/31166) shows one way to solve it.  I'm sure there is a better way, but since you don't need BizTalk, this seems like a quick and easy answer :)

Basically you comment out the BizTalk tasks.

you go to this folder (from your error message above):
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks\

and edit this file:
Microsoft.Sdc.Common.tasks

to comment out or remove the tasks for BizTalk.  Those lines all start looking like:

> <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(TasksPath)Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.BizTalk.dll"

and are at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Haven't looked into it yet, but it sounds like a plausible answer - I reverted back to WebDeployment 9.0 to avoid this problem, however I'll test this solution and mark it as an answer if it works.. Thanks.